# Remove no complete opening code html tag or with no follower

Tags: php, regex, string

I may get some html code strings with *code* html tags. The strings will be cut to get excerpts of them. Breaking can be only on spaces. So I may get such a strings:

```
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Lorem ipsum'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">a'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab'
```

The *code* opening tags that are not complete or are being complete but have nothing after them, should be deleted.

So in the example the first, the second and the last strings must remain untouched. From the strings from the third to to the fourth, the opening *code* tag must be removed.

So the result of the set of the strings should be like that:

```
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Lorem ipsum'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">a'
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab '
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab '
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab '
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab '
'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab'
```

I tried to find regex. Then I would get the length of uncomleted tags and use php *substr* function, but did not succeed:

```
(<code.+?)(?!.+>.+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dY5tW4/2

What regex would do the job or what php code?
Thank you

Comment: Can you say again why `'abc <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">Hello</code> ab <code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">'` should be trimmed ? If it's line bassed you could just remove the dot-all modifier https://regex101.com/r/dY5tW4/3

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Comment: Because this `<code asdfas = "fasd fdsa">` has no content. The content is this what follows the opening tag.

Comment: I need this for blog that I build in php. Articles may contain some code for highlighting it to present in blog article. It will be also some views that articles will be trimmed to show only short excerpt of them. When the break is in the code for highlighting the part before the break will be presented and highlighted. When the break is just after the opening code tag it will be nothong to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can parse that string looking for a complete `<code ..>` it would be
like this `<code[^>}*>`

All you have to do is put the part that's won't make it correct into a negative
lookahead assertion.

`(?s)<code(?![^>]*?>).*$`

Test https://regex101.com/r/dY5tW4/4

Expanded

```
 (?s)
 <code
 (?! [^>]*? > )
 .* 
 $
```

---

To make it have content, a slight modification is needed.

`(?s)<code(?![^>]*?>\s*\S).*$`

Expanded

```
 (?s)
 <code
 (?! [^>]*? > \s* \S )
 .* $
```

Remember, this does not follow any parsing rules for html, since it cannot.
Therefore, the best you can do is to get the remainder of the string after
a match.
In fact, it can't match multiple times in a string because there are  no
rules to do so.

Comment: This is what I need. With a nice explanation. Thanks a million, @sln.